# Show pc with static IP on dynamic IP router

Tags: router, ip, dhcp

I have a router with dynamic DHCP where I created some fixed addresses for some things I want to use with dyndns.
The problem is, that I have a pc/server which does not support DHCP/dynamic IP, so I have a static IP on this one (instead of only static IP for it on the router + PC in DHCP mode), which is the reason it won't show on my router's interface for portforwarding.
How can I make it show in the interface?

I have some OEM router from my ISP, but maybe the software/firmware version can help: 4.8.3.DWVV_TAU_5.3.5

Comment: If your router won't let you put in an address manually then it needs to be taken out back and shot.

Comment: If this is a [Pirelli Router](http://www.dieschmids.at/18-pirelli/49887-4-8-3-dwvv-tau-5-3-5-alte-firmware-flashen-um-als-router-zu-nutzen) you should be able to just type in an IP in the port-forwarding page. See [here](http://www.dieschmids.at/6-ankuendigungen-und-faqs/39122-dyndns-adresse-und-portforwarding-am-pirelli).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from agreeing whole-heartedly with Ignacio's brilliant analysis, you may consider giving these pcs a *reserved address*. This may even be a better alternative to a static IP.

Let your pc get a DHCP address, then go the router's GUI, and check where it says: *Address Reservation* or some such thing. You can then associate the MAC address of the pc in question which is *currently connected* with the IP address it currently holds, in such a way that that address will never be given to any interface with a different MAC address, and that the given MAC address will *always* receive the same IP address.

Be careful: if you change the interface your pc connects to your LAN (for instance, wifi instead of ethernet) it will **not** receive the reserved IP address because the MAC number is not the one for which the reservation has been made.